# Website page load time issues in iOS - Safari browsers

Tags: ios, wordpress, google-analytics, safari, page-load-time

We have a website in Wordpress, using a home-made theme. Some weeks ago, we noticed some page load time issues of our website, reported in Google Analytics. If we check the website using speed tests as Pingdom, Webpagetest and GTMetrix, we don’t see any performance issues. We checked the Analytics data, the main issues (average load time) are in iOS – Safari browsers (iPhone, iPad, in-app). If we check the specific data we find that, for example, one page could have 30 seconds page load time, but is not always and it happens for a single user using Safari 9 browser in Apple mobile device.

One more thing, we tested using those devices, but nothing weird happened.

Any idea what could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just about the mobile device but the carrier also.

Apparently your carrier is better than the other(s).

The second biggest issue with mobile carriers is the number of simultaneous requests allowed.  A desktop will download about 6 page resources simultaneously. Mobile, one, maybe two.

The biggest issue is the tower will often drop the radio signal between the phone and the tower between request.

so with mobile it is very important to minimize the number of requests per page.

Comment: Yes, speed is an issue. But, why we have some good numbers in other mobile devices-browsers? It looks like is a Safari issue, may be.